# Syncing a new node, prepopulate db with polkadot

Tags: polkadot, parachain, rocks-db

When syncing a new node from scratch it takes several days just to transfer and validate the polkadot chain. Comparing two runs reveals there are no simulates at all with the `sst` files.

Is there an officially supported way to populate the db with the finalized blocks before starting the new node to speed up this process? Ideally it should be something that works for both the parachain and the relaychain, which could be incorporated in our build system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--sync warp` to sync close to the tip of the chain. Or you can also use a database backup and start your node with this.